# Добавление пунктов в comboBox QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick

Всем привет! 
С QtQuick я дела никогда не имел. Всё писал на виджетах. Сейчас выдали проект с использованием QML. Всё хорошо, но есть одно НО.
Мне надо передать данные с виджета в comboBox QML

Дело вот в чем: я через QSerialPortInfo сканирую порты и сохраняю их в переменную, и emit'ом передаю в QML, с QML я их перехватываю и записываю в лейбу, которую сам и создал. Но теперь список портов нужно записать в comboBox. Перепробовал разное, в манах был, но пишет ошибку с TypeDef'ами

Вот код (очень простой):

**trans_data.h** мой класс

```
#ifndef TRANS_DATA_H
#define TRANS_DATA_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QVector>

class trans_data : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit trans_data(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void sendToQml(QString count);

public slots:
    void receivedFromQml(); //сканирование и передача портов
};

#endif // TRANS_DATA_H
```

**trans_data.cpp**

```
#include "trans_data.h"
#include <QDebug>
trans_data::trans_data(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
}

void trans_data::receivedFromQml()
{
    //Сканирую существующие порты и в тоже самое время сохраняю в переменную
    for(QSerialPortInfo ports : QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
        emit sendToQml(ports.portName()); //Эмитю порты
}
```

И вот сам qml файл:
**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Connections {
        target: transData
        onSendToQml: {
            labelCount.text = count //запись всех портов в лейбу
        }
    }

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent

        //Лейба куда я пишу порты
        Text {
            id: labelCount
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            height: 300
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            text: "Hello World!!!"
        } //

        //Кнопка по какой я сканирую порты
        button1.style: ButtonStyle {
            background: Rectangle {
                color: control.pressed ? "red" : "black"
                border.color: control.pressed ? "black" : "red"
                border.width: 2
                radius: 5
            }
            label: Text {
                text: qsTr("Scan ports")
                color: control.pressed ? "black" : "red"
            }
        } //

        //По клику на кнопку идет обращение в слот
        button1.onClicked: {
            transData.receivedFromQml()
        } //

        //комбоБокс в который я хочу записать данные
        ComboBox {
            id: comboList
//            currentIndex: 2
//            model: ListModel {
//                id: cbItems
//                ListElement { text: "Banana"; color: "Yellow" }
//                ListElement { text: "Apple"; color: "Green" }
//                ListElement { text: "Coconut"; color: "Brown" }
//            }
//            onCurrentIndexChanged: console.debug(cbItems.get(currentIndex).text + ", " + cbItems.get(currentIndex).color)
        } //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboList
    model: yourModel
} 

ListModel {
    id: yourModel
}

Connections {
    target: transData
    onSendToQml: {
        yourModel.append({"text": count});
    }
}
```

Я не знаю, что у Вас там в `count` — если там список, то пройдитесь по списку и так же делайте `append`

Comment: Да! Отлично! Все заработало. Все СОМ порты с comboBox'е.

Какое пиво Вы любите :) я угощаю :) 
Спасибо огромное :)

Comment: @razorqhex, просто пометьте ответ как решение, нажав галочку рядом с ним, этого будет достаточно :)

Comment: можно так ещё записать: comboBox1.model: listCOMPorts (это если использовать comboBox в режиме конструктора)